# Por que una std::list ocupa el mismo espacio para cualquier tipo de dato

Tags: c++, manejo-de-memoria

He hecho algunas pruebas de memoria usando el siguiente código

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
void reservar(int tamano, T valor, string tipo){

    cout<<"T : "<<tipo<<endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    list<T> arreglo;
    for(int i=0; i<tamano; i++){
        arreglo.push_back(valor);
    }
    cout<<endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    cout<<endl;
}

main(){
    int tamano = 50000000;

    reservar<int>(tamano, 10, "int");
    reservar<long long>(tamano, 10000, "long long");
    reservar<short>(tamano, 10, "short");
    reservar<char>(tamano, 'c', "char");
    reservar<double>(tamano, 10, "double");
}
```

y siempre independientemente del tipo de dato me ocupa la misma cantidad de memoria según el administrador de tareas de Windows, he hecho la misma prueba con arreglos de tipo apuntador, con std::vector y en ambos casos la ocupación de la memoria variaba así como el tiempo que tardaba, pero con std::list no sucede esto. ¿A que se puede deber esto? ¿Cual es la estructura de datos (preferiblemente del std) más eficiente?

Adjunto una imagen del adminsitrador de tareas de Windows para la prueba realizada en el codigo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ¿A que se puede deber esto?

Aquí entran en juego varios factores.

**Gestión de memoria**

Ahí no estás viendo el consumo de memoria de `std::list` sino la cantidad de memoria que el Sistema Operativo está asignando a tu aplicación.

El Sistema Operativo no gestiona la memoria a nivel de bits sino que la agrupa por paquetes, de tal forma que si tu haces, por ejemplo:

```
char *c = new char;
```

El Sistema Operativo no va a dar un byte en exclusiva a tu aplicación, sino que reservará un bloque de memoria y, de ese bloque, `new` elegirá un byte para tu puntero. En consecuencia, salvo que trabajes con objetos lo suficientemente grandes o con una cantidad inmensa de datos, no deberías notar grandes diferencias de uso de memoria al cambiar de un contenedor a otro.

**Alineamiento de memoria**

Asumo que estás trabajando con un equpo de 64 bits, dado que tienes 8GB de memoria (imposible con 32 bits).

A la hora de organizar la memoria podemos disponer los datos de forma secuencial o alineada. La ventaja del primero es que se consume menos memoria, mientras que el segundo ofrece unos tiempos de acceso mucho mejores:

```
struct
{
  int a;
  bool b;
  char c;
  double d;
};

                Secuencial                                   Alineada

| 01 | 02 | 03 | 04 | 05 | 06 | 07 | 08 |    | 01 | 02 | 03 | 04 | 05 | 06 | 07 | 08 |
|         a         |  b |  c | xxxxxxx |    |         a         | xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx |
|                   d                   |    |  b | xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx |
                                             |  c | xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx |
                                             |                   d                   |
```

Tu caso parece más bien el segundo. Lo que parece estar sucediendo es que `std::list` alinea la memoria en beneficio de los tiempos de acceso. Así cada elemento añadido a la lista consume 64 bits de memoria independientemente del tipo de dato.

> ¿Cual es la estructura de datos (preferiblemente del std) más eficiente?

Depende de lo que quieras hacer en cada momento.

El contenedor más genérico que existe es `std::vector`, pero para saber cual puede ser el más adecuado hay que atender a las necesidades de cada algoritmo.

A modo de ejemplo, puedes encontrar un benchmark entre `std::list` y `std::vector` en el [siguiente enlace](https://baptiste-wicht.com/posts/2012/11/cpp-benchmark-vector-vs-list.html).

Lo mejor es conocer cómo funciona cada tipo de contenedor y, por supuesto, hacer pruebas de rendimiento.

En cualquier caso pocas veces se trabaja con tiempos críticos o con un número ingente de datos. Bajo estas circunstancias, `std::vector` suele dar los mejores resultados.